# How access an image between desktop app and a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

This is an odd one. I have 2 projects working in the same solution in visual studio. DesktopApplication and WebsiteApplication.

Within the DesktopApplication i have a folder called Images. Here i have the images i am trying to retrieve.

I currently have code working with the WebsiteApplication to retrieve the file-name from a database and to show it in the ImageUrl. It is currently retrieving the file-name but i am unsure how to set it in the URL path for the image.

***Here is my current code.***

```
private void loadRecipeImage()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                //Fetching top recipe     
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Image FROM Recipe_Image WHERE Recipe_ID = '"+recipeid1.Text+"'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    recipeimg.ImageUrl = String.Format("//Images//{0}", dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {



            }

            con.Close();

        }
```

This current code is not showing the image at all. Its showing a red cross. Obviously this isnt finding the location for it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't store the image directly into the DB?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe No reason. But this way is possible. I just dont understand why its no fetching the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first step** is to move your images folder to a location easily accessible for your both projects. I'd suggest you to move it to eg : "C:\SharedImagesFolder". (in the end, this string will be into your app.config or web.config). This will make it easy also if you want to use a file server some day.

**Second step,** when you store your image within your desktop app, you should store into your DB

- An identifier (might be a unique name, an integer (simple ID) or a GUID
- File name (eg : myImage.jpg)
- A Guid (if this is not your identifier).

**Third step**, you modify slightly the way you write the file inside your folder. I suggest you to only use a GUID as an image name (that way, you are sure to not overwrite another file). This Guid will be the one stored in your DB.

**4th step** you need an action inside a controller that will receive an Id, and that will

```
public ActionResult GetFile(Guid id)
{
    var stream = new StreamReader(YOUR_FILE_PATH + "/" + id);
    return File(stream.ReadToEnd(), CONTENT_TYPE);
}
```